# Reading a file and putting it into a array but line 1 is null?

Tags: java

I've made a text file with 5 random strings in it and I am trying to get the contents into a array called "text".
The last 4 strings work fine but the first string is being printed as null?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Task4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("filepath");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = br.readLine();
        String[] txt = new String[5];
        do {
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                txt[i] = br.readLine();
            }
        } while ((line = br.readLine()) != null);
        System.out.println(txt[0]); // prints null
        System.out.println(txt[1]); // works fine
        System.out.println(txt[2]); // works fine
        System.out.println(txt[3]); // works fine
        System.out.println(txt[4]); // works fine
    }
}
```

*EDIT*

I've tried changing the for loop to start at 0 but it entirely skips out the first string and makes the last string ([txt[4]) print as null...

Comment: In `for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)` make `i = 0`

Comment: Tried that that makes txt[4] come out as null.

Comment: You're calling `readLine()` in three places. You're assigning one of the results to `line`, but then you're not using `line` inside your loop: you're just calling `readLine()` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared line variable like this,

```
String line = br.readLine();
```

which consumes the first line.

Just initialize it to null.

```
String line = null;
```

Besides make i = 0 in for loop instead of 1, which are causing issues. Also you read the line into line variable but don't assign it in array so remove that as well.

And you actually don't need a for loop inside while loop, and instead you can make your code like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("filepath");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String[] txt = new String[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        txt[i] = br.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(txt[0]); // prints null
    System.out.println(txt[1]); // works fine
    System.out.println(txt[2]); // works fine
    System.out.println(txt[3]); // works fine
    System.out.println(txt[4]); // works fine
    br.close();
}
```

Which will print all your five lines without any issues.

Comment: Thanks, works a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Well your loop is starting at `1` that is `txt[0]` is never assigned any value.

change

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

and you should be fine.

Additionally your first line is discarded as you are calling `br.readLine()` for the first time outside of your loop. And your resources (`FileReader` and `BufferedReader`) are not closed.

Change your code like this:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"))) {
    String[] txt = new String[5];
    int i = 0;
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && (i < 5)) {
        txt[i] = line;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried that that makes txt[4] come out as null.

Comment: Also entirely skips line 1 aswell for some reason.

Comment: @Rhys, see the edits to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the for loop, your int i start in the line number 1, instead of the number 0.

```
 for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
```

Should be

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Comment: Skips out the first string and prints txt[4] as null unfortunately.